# SwiftUI and CoreData: Horizontal bar chart with different coloured values

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am learning SwiftUI with CoreData and I have that one demo app where I am stuck.

Outcome:
I would like to present different coloured bar charts based on numeral values (calories). I managed to present numeral values with one colour, but not different colours based on value.

Here is image about desired outcome and my Swift code.

Thank you for any help! -Toni

[Desired UI outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur6XH.png)

[Code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0pXC.png)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ColourChart: View {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjContext
  @State private var name = ""
  @State private var calories: Double = 0
  @State private var color: Color = .gray
  
  @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.calories)]) var food: FetchedResults<CaloriesEntity>
  
    var body: some View {
      List {
          ForEach(food) { food in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
              HStack(alignment: .top) {
                Text(food.name ?? "Unknown name")
                  .onAppear {
                    calories = food.calories
                    name = food.name!
                  }
                Spacer()
                Text(calcTimeSince(date:food.date!))
                  .foregroundColor(.gray)
                  .font(.caption)
                  .italic()
              }///-HStack
              ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                  .foregroundColor(ColouredBars())
                  .frame(width: food.calories/3, height: 15, alignment: .trailing)
                  .cornerRadius(5)
                Text("\(Int(food.calories))")
                  .foregroundColor(.white)
                  .font(.caption)
              }///-ZStack
            }///-VStack
          }///ForEach Ends
      }///-List
    }///-View
  
  func ColouredBars() -> Color {
    let calories: Double = 299
    
    if calories > 600 {
      color = .red
    } else if calories > 300 {
      color = .yellow
    } else {
      color = .green
    }
    
    return color
  }
}///-Struct

struct ColourChart_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
      ColourChart()
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass calories into `ColouredBars` as a parameter -- not set state based on it.

Comment: @jnpdx Hi. Thank you for info. Do you have any example how could I do it? Unfortunately I am little bit rookie here. :)

Comment: By the way, typically we name functions with lowercase first letters in Swift.

Comment: Also, if you want that kind of rounded bar, rather than using a `Rectangle()` with a `cornerRadius`, use `Capsule()`. If you change the height of the `Rectangle()`, you may end up with a flat side. `Capsule()` always gives you a hemispherical end.

Comment: @jnpdx Thank you for the sample. I managed to add parameter to function, but when I try to call function editor gives error message: _italic_ "Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'Color?'" I added screenshot about my code in link next to other screenshot.

Comment: You need to change the return type of the function to `Color` and return a `Color` instead of returning a `Double`. So, don't set the state in that function to a `Color`, return it.

Comment: I managed to succeed with that one! Excellent help from you. Thank you @jnpdx and JerryC and Yrb for that useful tip to use capsule.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to add a calories parameter and change the return type to color. The code would look something like this:

```
func calorieColor(calorie: Double) -> Color {
  if calorie >= 600 {
    return .red
  } else if calorie >= 300 {
    return .yellow
  } else {
    return .green 
  }
   return .clear
}
```

the .clear is there just to allow the function to return some type of color if the if statement isn't applicable but that shouldn't be the case.

You could also do func calorieColor(_ calorie: Double) -> Color { The _ allows you to make the code a little more concise by allowing you to just type calorieColor(150) vs calorieColor(Calorie: 150).

Comment: You have a brace turned the wrong direction in `{ else {`. Also, this might be a little Swift-ier with a `switch` statement.

Comment: Oo good catch and true.